# Reset a HTML5 "number" field containing text using AngularJS in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome

## Use Case

I have a number field that specifically says "*Enter a number*". The end user will invariably enter a string. When the user clicks the "Reset" button using Google Chrome, the number fields containing text will not reset.

The requirements are:

- Users cannot be upgraded to follow instructions. **:D**
- Clicking the reset button should default the number back to *undefined*.
- Ideally, we'd like to keep the `type="number"` attribute as it allows for the keypad to popup on mobile devices.

### Code

A [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ59f/1/) demo is available.

#### Angular Template

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <p>
        Enter a string into the "number" field. Clicking any of the buttons
        will not clear the field.
    </p>
    <p>
        Enter a number into the "number" field. Clicking any of the buttons
        will clear the field.
    </p>
    <input type="number" ng-model="someValue" placeholder="Enter a number"/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="set('hello, world!')">Set to Hello, World!</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="set(undefined)">Set to undefined</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="set('')">Set to empty string</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="set(0)">Set to zero</button>
</div>
```

#### Angular Application & Controller

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.someValue = undefined;
    $scope.set = function(val) {
        $scope.someValue = val;
    };
});
```

### Question

- How do you reset a number field to undefined (or blank) containing an invalid value within Angular?

Comment: The fiddle seems to work for me, maybe I don't understand the problem.  When I enter invalid text and click any of those buttons (besides the one that sets it to 0, which is a valid number) reset the input to empty

Comment: @Tom Oh maybe this is browser specific.. let me check.. Which browser are you using? As an example, if I enter "Hello, World!" into the number field and click any of the buttons, none of them will set the number field to blank.

Comment: @Tom Just tested, it appears to be a "Google Chrome" problem only.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem (which I see with Chrome as well) but what if you change it to a `text` field, then use `ng-pattern` to mark the field as invalid if it has any non-number characters in it, then disable the submit button if the field is invalid? You can then also conditionally style the field if there's invalid text (put a red box around it, make an error message pop up, whatever).

Comment: @CanSpice I guess that's a solution. I'd like to keep it as number since the keypad pops up when used on tablets, but guess a browser detection script can be used to check if its on a tablet or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

It appears that this can be resolved using a directive, but I was hoping for a less invasive solution as this directive will fire for any input. However, it does what is required. It appears that entering strings into number fields breaks things with Google Chrome and Angular.

### Directive

```
.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (attrs.type.toLowerCase() !== 'number') {
                return;
            } //only augment number input!
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return value ? parseFloat(value) : null;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your field is required, so say it to Angular!

http://jsfiddle.net/TQ59f/10/

```
<input type="number" ng-model="someValue" required="true" placeholder="Enter a number"/>
```

Note that setting `undefined` as your number's value won't clear the number input. However, setting a non-numeric string as a value (like `hello world`) will clear the field, as it isn't numeric.

**Edit**: directive way found by poster mister_rampage seems to be the AngularJS way to solve the problem without "required".

Comment: Odd that this works.. In our particular application the field isn't required though. The field, if left unanswered, should be blank because the statisticians that analyse the data need to distinguish between unanswered and a numeric value.

Comment: Okay so this ain't no solution for you, the directive way is way better. Note that you could create a new directive name and use it in your input definition like `<input type="number" ng-model="someValue" placeholder="Enter a number" checkNaN />`. Very interesting case, thanks.

Comment: +1 Thanks for spending the time. I like the specific directive case for using `checkNaN`. It's definitely cleaner than a blanket `input` directive.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks! Directives are among the core concepts of AngularJS and this is a good and flexible choice in your situation. If you've found a precise solution, please post it as a separate answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem when trying to clear the field.  I was able to solve this by first setting the model value to a number then explicitly setting it to null wrapped in a $timeout so it occurs after the $digest.

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/el947PDAtmm0En8Q1jP8)

You might be able to do it with something similar (make sure you inject $timeout!).

```
angular.module('app', [$timeout])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.someValue = undefined;
    $scope.set = function(val) {
        $scope.someValue = 1;
        $timeout(funciton () {
            $scope.someValue = val
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: That's a clever solution as well. I guess setting it to a number first always ensures that it's proper before overwriting it.